# WXR XML import is stripping php tags that I need to keep

Tags: php, filters, import

When I import my `WXR XML` file it appears that wp_insert_post (or another function) is applying filters to strip php tags that I need to keep in my content.

I have searched the various wp-include php files to locate:
`wp_insert_post`, `sanitize_post`, `wp_strip_all_tags`

But I have no clue as to what files to edit and what edits to make to keep from stripping the php tags.

Advice and assistance greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally, a feed doesn't hold `php` tags. Please show all your code and what you're doing exactly (use the edit link).

Answer (score 0):

**Changing WordPress -- installed all the right plugins?**
Just wondering are you migrating WordPress? ... Did you have a plugin like [Exec-PHP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/) allowing PHP content in posts and pages on one install and that plugin is not active in another install of WordPress?

WordPress by default doesn't allow PHP in posts and pages so this could be your problem.

**Check your WordPress database with PHPMyAdmin or any other SQL tool**
You should also browse your WordPress database and check if the  content is there in one of the posts.   It's not likely that the importer stripped out your code.